# Is my field algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

For a field $L$, let $\widetilde L$ be the splitting field of all irreducible polynomials over $L$ having **prime-power degree**.

> **Question**: Do we have $\widetilde{\mathbf Q}=\overline{\mathbf Q}$?

My money is on "no", because I see no obvious reason why it should be true. If the answer is indeed negative, can one say what degree occurs as the smallest degree of an $f\in \mathbf Q[X]$ which does *not* split in $M$?

In any case, it seems quite difficult (to me)...

*A variation*:  We have a chain $$L \subset \widetilde L \subset \widetilde {\widetilde L} \subset \dots$$
Let $\widehat L$ be the limit of this chain. Is it even true that $\widehat{\mathbf Q}=\overline{\mathbf Q}$? Does the chain stabilize? The field $\widehat{\mathbf Q}$ has the strange property of having no finite extensions of prime-power degree. Correspondingly, the Galois group $\text{Gal }(\overline{\mathbf Q}/\widehat{\mathbf Q})$ has the strange property of having no open subgroups of prime-power index...

For $L$ a finite field, it is easy to see that $\widetilde{L}=\overline{L}$. We obviously have $\widetilde{\mathbf R}=\overline{\mathbf R}$. I do not know if $\widetilde{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$, or if $\widehat{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$. (*Edit*: Every finite Galois extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ is solvable, and I believe it follows from this that $\widehat{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$.)

(I have asked this on MSE: please see the [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803682/is-my-field-algebraically-closed) there.)

Comment: Obviously $\tilde{L}$ contains all abelian (or even nilpotent) Galois extensions of $L$, and therefore $\hat{L}$ contains all solvable extensions of $L$.

Comment: The question is tricker than one could expect (see the discussion on MSE!). For instance it's possible that $L$ contains a Galois extension of $L$ with Galois group the alternating group $A_6$. Indeed, let $A_6$ act on $F_p^5$ in a standard way. Then in the semidirect product $G=A_6\ltimes F_p^5$, the intersection of conjugates of $A_6$ is trivial. Thus if one has a Galois extension $L\subset L'$ with Galois group $G$, then this Galois extension is generated by splitting fields of polynomial of $p$-power degree. (...)

Comment: (...) because $A_6$ has $p$-power index in $G$ and the intersection of conjugates of $A_6$ in $G$ is trivial. On the other hand, $L'$ admits a smaller Galois extension $L''$ with Galois group $A_6$ over $L$, which contains no subextension $\neq L$ of prime power degree (because $A_6$ has no proper subgroup of prime power index), still we have $L''\subset L'\subset\tilde{L}$. Such extensions can be found on a suitable field of characteristic zero, and probably over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}$Building on YCor's construction, your field is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let $L$ be any finite Galois extension of $\QQ$ with Galois group $G$; I will show that $L$ is contained in your field.

We can find an element $x$ in $L$ so that, for any nonempty subset $S$ of $G$, the product $\prod_{\sigma \in S} x^{\sigma}$ is not square. For example, choose $x$ to generate a principal prime ideal of $L$ lying over a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is completely split in $L$. Let $M$ be the result of adjoining to $L$ all square roots $\sqrt{x^{\sigma}}$, for all $\sigma \in G$. So $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/2)^G$, where the first $G$ acts by permuting the factors in the second $G$.

Let $F \subset M$ be the fixed field of $G \ltimes \{ 0 \}$. This group has index $2^{|G|}$ in $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$, so $[F:\QQ]=2^{|G|}$. Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of a primitive element of $F$. So $f$ splits in your field. Thus, your field contains $F$ and all Galois conjugates of $F$. But the intersection $\bigcap_{h \in G \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/2)^G} h (G \ltimes \{ 0 \}) h^{-1}$ is trivial, so the collection of Galois conjugates of $F$ generates $M$. We have shown that your field contains $M$, and hence contains $L$.

Comment: Nice. In other words, this shows that every Galois extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ of degree $d$ is contained in the splitting field of a polynomial of degree $2^d$ (the splitting field having degree $d2^d$).

Comment: Very nice (and, for me, unexpected!)

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Why is the extension $1\to(\mathbf{Z}/2)^G\to Gal(M/\mathbf{Q})\to G\to 1$ split?

Comment: @YCor There really should be an elementary proof that I'm not seeing, but here is a sophisticated one: There are no nontrivial extensions of the form $1 \to A^G \to E \to G \to 1$ (with $A$ an abelian group and the obvious $G$ action on $A^G$.) See Corollary II.1.12 of http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf , stated in the form $H^r(G, \mathrm{Ind}_{1}^G(A)) =0$ for $r>0$.

Comment: I guess that the fact that your proof works as such is equivalent to the non-existence of such extensions, at least if one believes that every finite group is a Galois group over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @YCor Here is a proof without group cohomology. For each $\sigma \in G$, choose $y_{\sigma}$ in $M$ with $y_{\sigma}^2 = x^{\sigma}$. Let $\Gamma$ be the subgroup of $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$ taking the set $\{ y_{\sigma} \}_{\sigma \in G}$ to itself. I claim that $\Gamma \subset Gal(M/\mathbb{Q}) \to G$ is an isomorphism. Then the inverse map $G \to \Gamma \subset Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$ is a splitting. (continued)

Comment: Injectivity: If $h$ is in the kernel of $ Gal(M/\mathbb{Q}) \to G$, then $h$ fixes each $x_{\sigma}$ and hence $h(y_{\sigma})= \pm y_{\sigma}$; if $h \in \Gamma$ then we get $h(y_{\sigma})=y_{\sigma}$. The $y$'s generate $M$, so $h=1$. (continued)

Comment: Surjectivity: Let $g \in G$ and choose an arbitrary preimage $h \in Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$. Then $h(y_{\sigma}) = \epsilon_{\sigma} y_{h \sigma}$ for some $\epsilon_{\sigma} \in \pm 1$. Considering $\epsilon$ as a point of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^G$, we see that $h \epsilon$ is a preimage of $g$ in $\Gamma$.

Comment: OK, interesting. So I guess there is an exotic proof of the splitting theorem (for finite groups) without homological algebra, consisting in finding a Galois extension with Galois group $E$ (this can always be done, since we do not prescribe the ground field, say with a number field) and running the argument.

Comment: Right, but probably working harder than is necessary: The field was just being used as a convenient thing for the groups to act on. I think the following is a restatement in the language of groups: Given $1 \to A^G \to E \to G \to 1$, choose a set-theoretic section $s: G \to E$. Define $\Gamma \subset E$ to be the group sending the set $s(G)$ to itself. I think you should get that $\Gamma \to G$ is an isomorphism. (Maybe I'll assign this next time I teach group theory :).)

Comment: Great, this is a nice simple proof!

Comment: The elementary argument in my last comment is broken (I want to choose a section of a 2 to 1 map, not a $2^G$ to $1$ map.) I think the right version is to set $X = E/A^{G \setminus \{ e \}}$ and choose a section of $X \to E/A^G = G$. But I'm not going to sweat getting this right, since the Galois theory argument and the group cohomology argument work.

Comment: Dear David: if you'd like to post your beautiful answer at MSE also, I'll happily accept it there as well. Cheers!